Terraform error reading AWS when AWS CLI succeeds
I'm new to Terraform.  Starting with something simple gives me an error about not being authorized.  However running the equivalent command on the AWS CLI yields the expected output.  Before running any of these commands, aws sso login was run successfully to handle authentication.
I tried double checking version numbers to make sure I had the newest versions.  I thought about downgrading something (Terraform, hashicorp/aws, aws cli) to see if bugs were introduced, but I don't know what are valid versions and/or compatible versions.  For that matter, I only assume the current versions are compatible.
AWS Cli Output
% aws ec2 describe-subnets --subnet-ids subnet-XXXX --region "us-west-2"
{
    "Subnets": [
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2a",
            "AvailabilityZoneId": "XXX",
            "AvailableIpAddressCount": XXX,
            "CidrBlock": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/XX",
            "DefaultForAz": false,
            "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
            "MapCustomerOwnedIpOnLaunch": false,
            "State": "available",
            "SubnetId": "subnet-XXXX",
            "VpcId": "vpc-XXXX",
            "OwnerId": "XXXX",
            "AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation": false,
            "Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": [],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "XXXXX"
                }
            ],
            "SubnetArn": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:XXXXX:subnet/subnet-XXXXX",
            "EnableDns64": false,
            "Ipv6Native": false,
            "PrivateDnsNameOptionsOnLaunch": {
                "HostnameType": "ip-name",
                "EnableResourceNameDnsARecord": false,
                "EnableResourceNameDnsAAAARecord": false
            }
        }
    ]
}


Terraform Output
% terraform plan
data.aws_subnet.private1: Reading...

Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: reading EC2 Subnet: operation error EC2: DescribeSubnets, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: XXX-XX-XX-XX-XXXXXXX, api error UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:user/XX@XXX is not authorized to perform: ec2:DescribeSubnets with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy
│ 
│   with data.aws_subnet.private1,
│   on temp.tf line 21, in data "aws_subnet" "private1":
│   21: data "aws_subnet" "private1" {

Versions
% terraform version
Terraform v1.9.3
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.61.0
% aws --version 
aws-cli/2.17.26 Python/3.11.9 Darwin/23.5.0 exe/x86_64

Terraform file:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.61"
    }
  }
  required_version = "~> 1.9.3"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
    profile = "default"
}

variable "aws_region" {
  type = string
  default = "us-west-2"
}

data "aws_subnet" "private1" {
  id = "subnet-XXXX"
}

AWS config (~/.aws/config)
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXX
region = us-west-2
sso_session = default
sso_account_id = XXXXX
sso_role_name = XXX

[sso-session default]
sso_start_url = https://XXXX.awsapps.com/start
sso_region = us-west-2
sso_registration_scopes = sso:account:access


why you are using aws_access_key_id  and aws_secret_access_key  if you are using sso ? this is generated and managed automatically for aws cli that it's supporting SSO (.aws/sso and .aws/cli). but  terraform doesn't check for this credentials so you need to manage it yourself in some way that uses the access and secret key generated

That was it.  It was an evolution issue with those values.  I removed them and now it all works as expected.  I figured it was something like that.  Thank you very much.

glad that helped !
